# Выбор дизайна или Выбор дизайнов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Если говорить про торты, то как правильнее сказать?

> Огромный выбор дизайна

или

> Огромный выбор дизайнов

Answer (score 4):

***Огромный выбор вариантов оформления;

огромный выбор вариантов дизайна.***

*― «Это наше ноу-хау, извините». ― «Покажите хоть непригодившиеся варианты дизайна пачки!» ― «Рады бы, но это интеллектуальная собственность нашего рекламного агентства»*. [Олег Алямов. Новые русские сигареты (1997) // «Столица», 1997.10.28]

*Огромный выбор дизайна* звучит как-то неправильно.

Answer (score 2):

**О грамматике сочетания**

**Дизайн** (ед.ч.) изделия – это **художественное оформление** изделия.

Можно сказать: выбор вариантов **художественного оформления** изделия/выбор вариантов **дизайна** изделия.

А далее: огромный (большой, широкий)  выбор вариантов дизайна.

ВЫБОР. 3. То, из чего можно выбрать; подбор каких-л. предметов; ассортимент. **Широкий в. товаров.**

Answer (score 0):

Слово "дизайн" к тортам вряд ли применимо.

ДИЗАЙН, -а; м. [от англ. desighn - проектировать, конструировать] 1. Проектирование художественных форм, внешнего вида изделий, производимых промышленностью, фасадов зданий, интерьеров помещений и т.п.; художественное конструирование. Современный д. Художник по дизайну. Заниматься дизайном. 2. Разг. Художественно оформленный внешний вид изделия. Любоваться дизайном автомобиля. <Дизайнерский (см.).

Второе значение как будто бы подходит, но все же нет. Торт не автомобиль, да и к автомобилю "огромный выбор дизайна (или дизайнов)" вряд ли подойдет. Это очень корявый русский язык.

Comment: А при чем тут автомобиль? Разве к изделию оносится только автомобиль? Прочитайте в словаре значение слово изделие. Торт - кондитерское изделие.

Comment: @Серж В статье из толкового словаря приведен пример с автомобилем. А так-то конечно, изделий множество. Но далеко не к каждому применимо слово "дизайн". Тем более в сочетании с "огромным выбором". Екатерина Каштанова очень правильно же ответила.

Answer (score -1):

Слово "дизайн" не имеет формы мн. ч. Поэтому правильно: Огромный выбор дизайна.

Comment: Поставившей минус - пусть обоснует причину.

Comment: Он считает, наверное, что выбор дизайна (одного среди других) подразумевает, что их множество. Т. е. любой ответ из предложенных нужно похоронить и дать свой.

Comment: @shampar, кто он?

Comment: Автор минуса... Может быть, и сам выскажется.

Comment: А-а, понятно. Может быть.

Comment: *Слово "дизайн" не имеет формы мн. ч.* Совершенно верно. *Поэтому правильно: Огромный выбор дизайна.* А вот это совершенно неверно. Автор минуса.

Comment: Вопрос был о грамматике, а не о стилистике.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к минусу. Нельзя же предлагать невозможный вариант ответа, оправдывая его тем, что автор вопроса спрашивала о грамматике, а не о стилистике (я, правда, не понял, почему Вы так решили, но это мне не важно в данном случае).

Comment: @grizzly, Ну тогда мне тоже надо многим минусы лепить. Я учту это в следующий раз.